# Como adicionar um campo de pesquisa na minha Gridview - ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, gridview

Pessoal estou agarrado em uma etapa:

Eu tenho uma GridView que foi feita manualmente porém não estou conseguindo de forma alguma adicionar um campo de pesquisa que possa fazer uma busca dentro.

Como posso fazer tal implementação?

Obrigado!

**HTML Markup**

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Layout/Principal.Master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="EstornoOrdemRecebidaIncorretamente.aspx.cs"
    Inherits="Inventario.View.Paginas.EstornoOrdemRecebidaIncorretamente" %>
    <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:Content>
    <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
        <br />
        <p>
            <center>
                <h3>Estorno - Ordem Recebida Incorretamente</h3>
            </center>
        </p>
        <p>
            <center>
                <!-- A marcação HTML a seguir consiste em um controle GridView com a propriedade AutoGenerateColumns 
            definida como true. A fim de geradas automaticamente editar e excluir botões, o AutoGenerateEditButton 
            e AutoGenerateDeleteButton propriedades são definidas como true. 
            O GridView é especificado com os eventos OnRowDataBound, OnRowEditing, OnRowCancelingEdit, OnRowUpdating e OnRowDeleteting.-->

                ORDEM:
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Pesquisar" />
                <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="COD MOVIMENTACAO"
                    OnRowDeleting="OnRowDeleting" AllowPaging="True" OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging"
                    CellPadding="4" CellSpacing="1" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="COD MOVIMENTACAO" HeaderText="COD MOVIMENTACAO" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="PARTNUMBER" HeaderText="PARTNUMBER" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="CABREC" HeaderText="CABREC" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="QUANT MOVIMENTACAO" HeaderText="QUANT MOVIMENTACAO" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="COD POSICAO 1" HeaderText="COD POSICAO 1" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="COD POSICAO 2" HeaderText="COD POSICAO 2" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="TIPO MOVIMENTACAO" HeaderText="TIPO MOVIMENTACAO" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="COD TIPO SAIDA" HeaderText="COD TIPO SAIDA" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="QUANTIDADE" HeaderText="QUANTIDADE" />
                        <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Delete"
                                    Text="Estornar"
                                    OnClientClick="return confirm('Você realmente deseja estornar este registro?');" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>
                    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
                    <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" ForeColor="White" Font-Bold="True" />
                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
                    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
                    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
                    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
                    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
                </asp:GridView>
            </center>
        </p>
    </asp:Content>
```

**C#**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

namespace Inventario.View.Paginas
{
    public partial class EstornoOrdemRecebidaIncorretamente : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated == false)
            {
                Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx");
            }

            if (!this.IsPostBack)
            {
                this.BindGrid();
            }

        }
        private void BindGrid()
        {
            string INVENTARIOConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["INVENTARIOConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(INVENTARIOConnectionString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM MOVIMENTACAO_POSICAOPECA_VI"))
                {
                    using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                    {
                        cmd.Connection = con;
                        sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                        using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                        {
                            sda.Fill(dt);
                            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                            GridView1.DataBind();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LinkButton lb = (LinkButton)sender;
            GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)lb.NamingContainer;
            if (row != null)
            {

                TextBox tb = (TextBox)row.FindControl("TextBox1");
                string searchText = tb.Text;
            }
        }


        // ***Excluindo registros GridView***
        // Quando o botão Excluir é clicado, o manipulador de eventos OnRowDeleting do GridView é disparado.
        // CustomerId, que é a chave primária, é obtido da propriedade DataKey de GridView e, 
        // usando o CustomerId, o registro é excluído da tabela do banco de dados.
        protected void OnRowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
        {

            string MOV_COD = Convert.ToString(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values[0]);
            string INVENTARIOConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["INVENTARIOConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            string CURRENTUSER = User.Identity.Name;
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(INVENTARIOConnectionString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE MOVIMENTACAO SET ESTORNO_USUARIO = @CURRENTUSER, ESTORNO_DATAHORA = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE MOV_COD = @MOV_COD; UPDATE POSICAOPECA SET ESTORNO_USUARIO = @CURRENTUSER, ESTORNO_DATAHORA = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE POSPART = @MOV_COD"))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MOV_COD", MOV_COD);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CURRENTUSER", CURRENTUSER);
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    con.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();
                }
            }
            this.BindGrid();
        }
        protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
        {
            GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
            BindGrid(); //bindgridview will get the data source and bind it again
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver meu problema:

1 - editando BindGrid():

```
        private void BindGrid()
        {
            string INVENTARIOConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["INVENTARIOConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(INVENTARIOConnectionString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM MOVIMENTACAO_POSICAOPECA_VI WHERE PARTNUMBER LIKE '%' + @ORDEM + '%'"))
                {
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ORDEM", txtSearch.Text.Trim());
                    using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                    {
                        cmd.Connection = con;
                        sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                        using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                        {
                            sda.Fill(dt);
                            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                            GridView1.DataBind();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

2 - Adicionando Search()

```
        protected void Search(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.BindGrid();
        }
```

Código Completo:

**HTML Markup**

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Layout/Principal.Master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="EstornoOrdemRecebidaIncorretamente.aspx.cs"
    Inherits="Inventario.View.Paginas.EstornoOrdemRecebidaIncorretamente" %>
    <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:Content>
    <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
        <br />
        <p>
            <center>
                <h3>Estorno - Ordem Recebida Incorretamente</h3>
            </center>
        </p>
        <p>
            <center>
                <!-- A marcação HTML a seguir consiste em um controle GridView com a propriedade AutoGenerateColumns 
            definida como true. A fim de geradas automaticamente editar e excluir botões, o AutoGenerateEditButton 
            e AutoGenerateDeleteButton propriedades são definidas como true. 
            O GridView é especificado com os eventos OnRowDataBound, OnRowEditing, OnRowCancelingEdit, OnRowUpdating e OnRowDeleteting.-->

                ORDEM:
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server" />
                <asp:Button Text="PESQUISAR" runat="server" OnClick="Search" />
                <p>
                    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="COD MOVIMENTACAO"
                        OnRowDeleting="OnRowDeleting" AllowPaging="True"
                        OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" CellPadding="4" CellSpacing="1"
                        ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="PARTNUMBER" HeaderText="ORDEM" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="COD MOVIMENTACAO" HeaderText="COD MOVIMENTACAO" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="CABREC" HeaderText="CABREC" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="QUANT MOVIMENTACAO" HeaderText="QUANT MOVIMENTACAO" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="COD POSICAO 1" HeaderText="COD POSICAO 1" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="COD POSICAO 2" HeaderText="COD POSICAO 2" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="TIPO MOVIMENTACAO" HeaderText="TIPO MOVIMENTACAO" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="COD TIPO SAIDA" HeaderText="COD TIPO SAIDA" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="QUANTIDADE" HeaderText="QUANTIDADE" />
                            <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" CausesValidation="False"
                                        CommandName="Delete" Text="Estornar"
                                        OnClientClick="return confirm('Você realmente deseja estornar este registro?');" />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                        </Columns>
                        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
                        <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" ForeColor="White" Font-Bold="True" />
                        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                        <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
                        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
                        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
                        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
                        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
                    </asp:GridView>
                </p>
            </center>
        </p>
    </asp:Content>
```

**C#**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Inventario.View.Paginas
{
    public partial class EstornoOrdemRecebidaIncorretamente : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated == false)
            {
                Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx");
            }

            if (!this.IsPostBack)
            {
                this.BindGrid();
            }

        }

        //***Preenchendo e pesquisando em GridView***
        //A função BindGrid é usada para preencher e implementar a pesquisa do GridView. Ele usa uma consulta SQL de pesquisa 
        //LIKE para buscar registros da tabela do banco de dados. Este método é chamado no manipulador de 
        //eventos Page_Load, bem como no manipulador de eventos Click do botão Pesquisar.
        protected void Search(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.BindGrid();
        }
        private void BindGrid()
        {
            string INVENTARIOConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["INVENTARIOConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(INVENTARIOConnectionString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM MOVIMENTACAO_POSICAOPECA_VI WHERE PARTNUMBER LIKE '%' + @ORDEM + '%'"))
                {
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ORDEM", txtSearch.Text.Trim());
                    using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                    {
                        cmd.Connection = con;
                        sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                        using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                        {
                            sda.Fill(dt);
                            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                            GridView1.DataBind();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // ***Excluindo registros GridView***
        // Quando o botão Excluir é clicado, o manipulador de eventos OnRowDeleting do GridView é disparado.
        // CustomerId, que é a chave primária, é obtido da propriedade DataKey de GridView e, 
        // usando o CustomerId, o registro é excluído da tabela do banco de dados.
        protected void OnRowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
        {

            string MOV_COD = Convert.ToString(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values[0]);
            string INVENTARIOConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["INVENTARIOConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            string CURRENTUSER = User.Identity.Name;
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(INVENTARIOConnectionString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE MOVIMENTACAO SET ESTORNO_USUARIO = @CURRENTUSER, ESTORNO_DATAHORA = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE MOV_COD = @MOV_COD; UPDATE POSICAOPECA SET ESTORNO_USUARIO = @CURRENTUSER, ESTORNO_DATAHORA = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE POSPART = @MOV_COD"))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MOV_COD", MOV_COD);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CURRENTUSER", CURRENTUSER);
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    con.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();
                }
            }
            this.BindGrid();
        }

        //*Paginação
        //O evento OnPageIndexChanging que é usado para executar a paginação no controle ASP.Net GridView.
        protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
        {
            GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
            BindGrid(); //bindgridview will get the data source and bind it again
        }


    }
}
```